# What jQuery ajax file upload plugin should I use?

Tags: jquery, file-upload

The plugin should allow **delete** the uploaded file and multiple file upload.

EDIT: Actually I am in a situation that I need to browse and delete some pictures in some uploaded folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Andrew Valums' Ajax Upload in the past, and it supports cancellable uploads and multiple uploads.  His page is [here](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).

It looks like his site has been updated and the demos page is pretty limited.  Looks like he updated the site when he updated the plug-in.  Probably a work-in-progress.  But the control works and I haven't had issues with it.  Hopefully it works for your situation.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/demo/). It suits your need. Hope it helps..

Comment: Those demos relies on Adobe Flash.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use swfUpload and there is a jQ plugin for it.

However these do not address your question of delete - you need to return a list of the files and then allow the user to select them, submit the selection and use server side code to handle the delete.

For example you could use swfu to upload the files, using events provided by swfu (and the jQ plugin for it) you cna know when file uploading is complete. The event can trigger a request to update the list of files displayed in the browser. The user can then select file/s from the list and submit for delete as required.